# Django invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Stalone'

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get the users that I'm marking as `True` on my website in `data['checked_users']`:

> ## `models.py`

```
class Player(models.Model):
    jucator = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1, related_name='jucator')
    porecla = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    selectat = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.jucator
```

> ## `views.py`

```
def check_user(request):
    data = dict()
    data['players'] = Player.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        list_of_checks = request.POST.getlist('checks[]')
        # data['checked_users'] = list_of_checks
        data['checked_users'] = Player.objects.filter(jucator__in=list_of_checks)
    return render(request, 'checkbox.html', data)
```

> ## `checkbox.html`

```
<body>
    {% block content %}
        <form action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
            <table>
                    {% if request.user.is_superuser %}
                        {% for user in players %}
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" name="checks[]" value="{{ user.jucator }}" title="selected_players">{{ user.jucator }}<br></td>
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>
                            </tr>
                    {% else %}
                        {% for user in players %}
                            <tr><td>{{ user.jucator }}</td></tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}
            </table>
        {% for player in checked_users %}
            {{ player }}
        {% endfor %}
        </form>
    {% endblock %}
</body>
```

If I try this, it shows the players:

```
data['checked_users'] = list_of_checks
```

If I try with filter, I get this error:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Stalone'
```

Comment: Can you post the values of list_of_checks and Player.objects.filter(jucator__in=list_of_checks) by editing your Q?

Comment: Change to `value="{{ user.jucator.id }}"` and try again.

Comment: i added the values

Comment: value of list_of_checks pls? you need to get the value from your view.py file

Comment: yea mean this? value="{{ player.jucator }}"

Comment: i don't understand which values, the values are posted in the picture: LilJon, Sobont and Jhonny

Comment: @nik_m can i ask you another thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put inside `value="{{ user.jucator }}"` the actual `id` of the `jucator` object. Not the `jucator` object itself.

So, change to this: `value="{{ user.jucator.id }}"`. Now you can query with `Player.objects.filter(jucator__in=list_of_checks)` since `list_of_checks` containts a list of integers (the `id`s of `jucator`s).